# How to separate provider extender for custom control with ngModel to a separate file in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I created custom control and connected it to `ngModel`. And now to reuse this code in a multiple components I want to separate it in a different file. Taking the following example -

```
import {Component, Provider, forwardRef} from "angular2/core";
import {ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, CORE_DIRECTIVES} from "angular2/common";

const noop = () => {};

const CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR = new Provider(
  NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, {
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomInput),
    multi: true
  });

@Component({
  selector: 'custom-input',
  template: `
      <div class="form-group">
        <label><ng-content></ng-content>
          <input class="form-control" 
                 [(ngModel)]="value" 
                 (blur)="onTouched()">
        </label>
      </div>
  `,
  directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class CustomInput implements ControlValueAccessor{

    //The internal data model
    private _value: any = '';

    //Placeholders for the callbacks
    private _onTouchedCallback: (_:any) => void = noop;

    private _onChangeCallback: (_:any) => void = noop;

    //get accessor
    get value(): any { return this._value; };

    //set accessor including call the onchange callback
    set value(v: any) {
      if (v !== this._value) {
        this._value = v;
        this._onChangeCallback(v);
      }
    }

    //Set touched on blur
    onTouched(){
      this._onTouchedCallback();
    }

    //From ControlValueAccessor interface
    writeValue(value: any) {
      this._value = value;
    }

    //From ControlValueAccessor interface
    registerOnChange(fn: any) {
      this._onChangeCallback = fn;
    }

    //From ControlValueAccessor interface
    registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
      this._onTouchedCallback = fn;
    }

}
```

Example taken from [here](http://almerosteyn.com/2016/04/linkup-custom-control-to-ngcontrol-ngmodel).

Then I'm separating this code -

```
const noop = () => {};

const CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR = new Provider(
  NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, {
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomInput),
    multi: true
  });
```

to `external-file.ts`:

```
import { forwardRef } from 'angular2/core';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from 'angular2/common';

const fr = forwardRef;

export function createExtendedProvider(customInput) {  
  return new Provider(
    NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, {
      useExisting: fr(() => { console.log(`Inside method ${customInput}`); return customInput; }),
      multi: true
    });
}
```

I'm calling it in the component like this -
 `const MD_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR =  providerExtender.createExtendedProvider(CustomInput);`

And when I try to run the app I'm getting the following error -

```
browser_adapter.js:77 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Token must be defined!
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:538)
    at eval (zone.js:515)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:323)
    at Object.NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke (ng_zone_impl.js:45)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:322)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:216)
    at eval (zone.js:571)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:356)
    at Object.NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask (ng_zone_impl.js:36)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:355)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:256)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:474)
    at HTMLDocument.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:426)BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.js:77ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.js:60(anonymous function) @ application_ref.js:194schedulerFn @ async.js:123SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:166SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:115Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:74Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:51Subject._finalNext @ Subject.js:124Subject._next @ Subject.js:116Subject.next @ Subject.js:73EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:112NgZone._zoneImpl.ng_zone_impl_1.NgZoneImpl.onError @ ng_zone.js:120NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.js:66ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:327Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:233_loop_1 @ zone.js:487drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: Token must be defined! ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: BaseException {message: "Token must be defined!", stack: "Error: Token must be defined!↵    at new BaseExcep…oke (webpack:///./~/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:426:22)"}message: "Token must be defined!"stack: "Error: Token must be defined!↵    at new BaseException (webpack:///./~/angular2/src/facade/exceptions.js?:17:23)↵    at new Key (webpack:///./~/angular2/src/core/di/key.js?:26:19)↵    at KeyRegistry.get (webpack:///./~/angular2/src/core/di/key.js?:65:22)↵    at Function.Key.get (webpack:///./~/angular2/src/core/di/key.js?:40:60)↵    at resolveFactory (webpack:///./~/angular2/src/core/di/provider.js?:365:54)↵    at resolveProvider (webpack:///./~/angular2/src/core/di/provider.js?:385:66)↵    at Array.map (native)↵    at Object.resolveProviders (webpack:///./~/angular2/src/core/di/provider.js?:393:31)↵    at Function.Injector.resolve (webpack:///./~/angular2/src/core/di/injector.js?:426:27)↵    at Function.DirectiveProvider.createFromType (webpack:///./~/angular2/src/core/linker/element.js?:100:82)↵    at ResolvedMetadataCache.getResolvedDirectiveMetadata (webpack:///./~/angular2/src/core/linker/resolved_metadata_cache.js?:27:50)↵    at Function.AppProtoElement.create (webpack:///./~/angular2/src/core/linker/element.js?:159:45)↵    at eval (viewFactory_Login:833:41)↵    at Object.evalExpression (webpack:///./~/angular2/src/facade/lang.js?:457:94)↵    at TemplateCompiler._createViewFactoryRuntime (webpack:///./~/angular2/src/compiler/template_compiler.js?:184:27)↵    at eval (webpack:///./~/angular2/src/compiler/template_compiler.js?:144:49)↵    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///./~/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:323:29)↵    at Object.NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke (webpack:///./~/angular2/src/core/zone/ng_zone_impl.js?:45:41)↵    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///./~/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:322:35)↵    at Zone.run (webpack:///./~/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:216:44)↵    at eval (webpack:///./~/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:571:58)↵    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack:///./~/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:356:38)↵    at Object.NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask (webpack:///./~/angular2/src/core/zone/ng_zone_impl.js?:36:41)↵    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack:///./~/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:355:43)↵    at Zone.runTask (webpack:///./~/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:256:48)↵    at drainMicroTaskQueue (webpack:///./~/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:474:36)↵    at HTMLDocument.ZoneTask.invoke (webpack:///./~/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:426:22)"__proto__: ErrorconsoleError @ zone.js:461_loop_1 @ zone.js:490drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
```

I noticed that when I'm calling `createExtendedProvider` function and passing `CustomInput` there, it is still undefined. So, could someone please give me a hint if it is possible to separate it to a different file and if it is - how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

To create the provider in an external file you can use it like

```
@Component({
  selector: 'custom-input',
  template: `
...
  `,
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [providerExtender.createExtendedProvider(forwardRef(() => CustomInput))]
})
export class CustomInput implements ControlValueAccessor{
```

and in the other file

```
export function createExtendedProvider(customInput) { 
  return new Provider(
    NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, {useExisting: customInput, multi: true});
}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/unFNPy?p=preview)

**Original**

This seems invalid

```
export function createExtendedProvider(customInput) {  
  return new Provider(
    NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, {
      useExisting: fr(() => { console.log(`Inside method ${customInput}`); return customInput; }),
      multi: true
    });
}
```

`useExisting` means that there needs to come a type that should be resolved by Angulars DI.

I guess this is what you want:

```
export function createExtendedProvider(customInput) {  
  return new Provider(
    NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, {
      useClass: customInput,
      multi: true
    });
}
```

Comment: Tried, but I'm getting -
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of NgModel!.
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined

Most likely because somehow customInput is still undefined at the point.

Comment: May I ask why you want to move to another file? This doesn't seem to bring any advantage.

Comment: To reuse it in other components where I need a ngModel, writing almost similar code in most components seems a bit redundant to me. 
Maybe I'm mistaken something, and there is a good reason I should not do it with this example?

Comment: Is my proposed solution then what you want?

Comment: **Important**: in the Plunker example used useExisting, not useClass. So write useExisting, or binding won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's a silly answer but I would say that you just need to specify the `CustomInput` component into the components (`directives` attribute) where you want to use it:

```
import {CustomInput} from './custom.input';

@Component({
  (...)
  template: `
    <custom-input [(ngModel)]="something" ngControl="test"></custom-input>
  `,
  directives: [CustomInput]
})
export class SomeOtherComponent {
  (...)
}
```

In fact, the value accessor is registered within the `providers` of the component itself so I can see no needs to separate them into two different modules.